# How to fetch featured videos using the YouTube API v3?

Tags: youtube-api

I use some standard feeds of YouTube API v2 like:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/recently_featured
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed_Music?time=today&v=2

Now, I want to switch to API v3, I have read the doc here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/

There are many resources types and methods, but it seems none is correspond to the old v2 standard feeds, is there any solution for the job ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use videoCategories and guideCategories for that.

[Here's the full blog.](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2013/09/what-to-watch-our-apis-can-help.html)

[GDL video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LcrG0_XTO9o).